# How to put a zip file to server with JMeter?

Tags: file, jmeter, zip, put

How to put a zip file to server with JMeter?

This is a sample curl command:

```
curl -i --noproxy '*' -H Content-Type:application/octet-stream -X PUT -T /home/eknoose/vmm/image/CXP2010034_2A-R2A893.zip  http://10.62.49.229:8083/vmm/api/configuration/uploadImage/CXP2010034_2A-R2A893.zip
```

I want to execute a lot of this kind command with a different filename, how to write the http request in `jmeter`, I have to use put and not post.

How to construct such a HTTP request with JMeter?

Thanks

Comment: Please check this blog post - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter/. Navigate to file upload using Put method. Courtesy - Dmitri Tikhanski

Answer (score 0):

The relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration would be something like:

[image]

[`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header in its turn can be added using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)

[image]

---

In general given you can successfully upload the file using curl you should be able to record the event using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) just make sure to:

1. [Configure curl to use JMeter as the proxy](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-proxies)
2. Copy the file(s) you will be uploading to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.